# Is this wrapper for !Sync types sound?

Tags: rust

I sometimes find myself using a `!Sync` type (eg [`bumpalo::Bump`](https://docs.rs/bumpalo/latest/bumpalo/struct.Bump.html)) as part of the implementation of a type I want to be `Sync`. Right now I do it with `unsafe impl Sync` for the outer type, and only touching the inner type in `&mut self` methods. But is it sound to encapsulate the unsafety with a wrapper like the following? In particular, are the `Send` bounds correct?

```
pub struct UnCell<T> {
    value: T
}

unsafe impl<T> Sync for UnCell<T> {}

impl<T> UnCell<T> {
    pub fn new(value: T) -> Self {
        Self { value }
    }
    pub fn into_inner(self) -> T {
        self.value
    }
    pub fn get(&mut self) -> &T {
        &self.value
    }
}
impl<T: Send> UnCell<T> {
    pub fn get_mut(&mut self) -> &mut T {
        &mut self.value
    }
}
```

Comment: Nitpick: What you call `unwrap()` is usually named `into_inner()`; `unwrap()` is reserved for panicking operations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not just it is sound, there is a pending PR to add a type, `Exclusive`, that will allow you to do that safely!

[[core] add `Exclusive` to sync - #97629](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/97629).

You don't even need the `Send` bound: for a mutable reference to be `Send`, [its referent should also be](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.61.0/src/core/marker.rs.html#687) - and thus if you've got a mutable reference on some thread, you can safely access the referent.

Comment: Oh, I see, the `Send` bound on `Sync` for `Mutex` is needed because it can move `T`s between threads via a shared ref, while this can't.